# Creating and updating products using the V3 API

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I've been using Bigcommerce's csv import to create and update simple products with c# and headless browser control. This is a relatively easy method as I can include custom fields, category names, images, GPS information, and all of the other fields that the csv import allows. Even so, my long term goal will be to move to the API. So far it appears that the API is very limited. For instance, instead of just including a category name with the new product, you have to include a category ID. As far as I can see, that would mean that for every new product I would have to create the categories for the product, then retrieve the category(s) id with an API call and lastly create the product. It appears that this is just the beginning. It appears that many of the fields that are easily included in the csv now have to be created and then attached to the product. Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I'm creating / updating products. Usually thousands at a time. These are simple products so I include categories, custom fields, GPS info, etc... with each product record. With the csv import this is all done with one row from the csv file. It just seems that the API requires that I manage each of these fields before I create the product. What I mean is that it appears that I have to create or retrieve a category id, create or retrieve a custom field id, on and on before I can create the product.

Comment: Is it true that in order to create or update a product you have to take all of these preliminary steps? I just seems so inefficient. The Bigcommerce examples that I'm able to find don't explain the full process of creating a product with these extra fields. I'm wondering if someone might be able to give me insight or a complete example.

Comment: "categories" is a required field when creating  products but there is no reason you can't simply assign them to an unassigned category to be managed later. To that same end it might make sense to create all applicable categories first. A lot of APIs will use the numeric ID instead of name of a field, as that is the primary identifier. Lots of ways to make this cooperate with your workflow